# Django timezone ET instead of EST/EDT

Tags: python, django, timezone, pytz

what timezone value should I use or what should I do to show "ET" instead of "EST" or "EDT"?Also I am using pytz for my functions. Thanks.

settings.py:

```
#currently this shows "EDT"
TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern'

#where this shows "EST"
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Cancun'
```

post_template.html:

```
#outputs Oct 30,2018, 5:38AM/EST
{{post.modified|date:"M d,Y, g:iA/e"}}
```

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is just to show "ET", you will likely need to do that yourself, as EST and EDT are likely to be display defaults. You probably shouldn't, though, since ET would be ambiguous.

If what you need is for the time zone to honor DST, you probably want America/New_York. While EST5EDT will honor DST for Eastern time, [America/New_York appears to be the canonical replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for that designation. From that list, you can see US/Eastern uses the same DST adjustment, but it's also deprecated, listing America/New_York as canonical.

America/Cancun does not use DST, so it will always show EST.

*Edit: To explicitly answer the question: Use* `TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'` *to properly display the time zone information, since ET is not a complete description of the current offset of Eastern time (EST or EDT).*

Comment: That's good information, but you didn't actually answer the OP's "what should I do" question. Can you write more about how to "do it yourself"?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I didn't include what you're referencing because it would introduce ambiguity in what the actual offset is, since ET does not communicate whether Eastern time is currently in DST or not. I've edited to make my recommendation more clear.

Answer (score -2):

`ET` is `Africa/Addis_Ababa`

[List of timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: that timezone is "EAT" sir.